# Send the data of this form to a gmail account via php

Tags: php, forms, gmail, send

I want to send the data from this form to a gmail account via php. Now if I send it nothing happens, include the spam folder.

```
    <label for="email" id="email">Email <span>*</span></label>
    <input type="email" id="" name="email">

     <div>
         <div>
            <label for="name" id="text">Nombre <span>*</span> </label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
         </div>
         <div>
            <label for="tlf-num">Teléfono <span>*</span> </label>
            <input id="tlf-num" type="text" name="tlf-num" >
        </div>
     </div>
    <div>
        <label for="message" id="#">Mensaje</label>
        <textarea contenteditable="false" name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR">
</form>
```

This is the php, I don´t know what is wrong. This code was works for me about three years ago on other website. I read about email headers and gmail style accounts which take problems on recibe but I don´t know. I´m feeling a bit confussing about whats happen.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['tlf-   num']) && isset($_POST['message']) != ""){

$nombre = $_POST['name'];
$mail = $_POST['email'];
$header = 'From: ' . $mail . " \r\n";
$header .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . " \r\n";
$header .= "Mime-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/plain";
$mensaje = "Nombre " . $nombre . " ";
$mensaje .= "Su e-mail es: " . $mail . " \r\n";
$mensaje .= "Mensaje: " . $_POST['message'] . " \r\n";
$mensaje .= "Enviado el " . date('d/m/Y', time());
$para = 'loquesea@gmail.com';
$asunto = 'Formulario contacto Web';

mail($para, $asunto, utf8_decode($mensaje), $header);
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    setTimeout( function() {
      window.location.href='https://loquesea.com';
    }, 1500)
     </script>";
}
else{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        alert('Revisa los datos');
        window.location.href='https://loquesea.com';
 </script>";
}

?>
```

I check my php.ini file after the first answer and have this configuration, maybe need to change something or add any option or something else?.

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
; SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
; smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path = "env -i /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i"

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail().
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header = On

; The path to a log file that will log all mail() calls. Log entries include
; the full path of the script, line number, To address and headers.
;mail.log =
; Log mail to syslog (Event Log on Windows).
;mail.log = syslog
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your php.ini file for mail settings. THe mail() function uses the parameters set in .ini file to send mails.

For Ubuntu:

Install sendmail

```
sudo apt-get install sendmail
```

Configure your host here

```
sudo vim /etc/hosts
```

(Vim is the text editor here)

Save it and run config for sendmail

```
sudo sendmailconfig
```

Finally, restart Apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Refer [this](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/configuring-sendmail-on-ubuntu-1404) link for more details

Comment: I add to the question the mail function I have in my php.ini

Comment: Which Operating System are u using?

Comment: The operating system is Ubuntu